# Joomla backend not shown correctly

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, backend

I'm using Joomla 2.5 and the backend is not shown correctly. It seems that the template is not loaded correctly.
This is my page:

http://www.fussball.tsg-kastel.de/administrator/

The page as such is shown correctly but as you see, the backend isn't...

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

1. Rename the admin templates folder on the host server (for a backup)
2. FTP transfer of an admin template folder from another Joomla site and then copy it from the FTP location using a file manager into the admin templates folder.

You could have a corrupt file or just missing some files from installation. This has happened to people before and by doing these two steps it seemed to solve their issue.

Hope this works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a fatal error. Go to configuration.php and change error reporting to development. This will render the error to the browser (alternatively check your apache error log). I predict you probably have a plugin problem -- perhaps your host updated PHP version for example.  Whatever it is, deal with that problem.